# Why don't Typekit Fonts Work When Viewed in Devices Over Localhost using Edge Inspect?

Tags: fonts, localhost, webfonts, typekit, adobe-edge-inspect

When using Edge Inspect to test sites running locally, Typekit fonts are not downloaded or rendered.

I have added localhost to the allowed domains in my Typekit kit and also added my machine's IP address.

The fonts render fine when viewed in a browser, just not on any devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding this answer as given by Adobe support in the hope it will help anyone else with this problem. The following is a direct quote:

> When you're browsing a local website via the hostname `localhost`,
>   which would not be accessible to any other devices on your network,
>   Edge Inspect automatically gets your machine's local IP address (which
>   is not the same as the external IP as shown on sites like
>   whatismyip.com) and sends that to the mobile apps. For instance, let's
>   say I have a Sinatra application running in Chrome on my Mac as
>   `http://localhost:4567`. My iPhone wouldn't be able to understand the
>   hostname "localhost", but it can see my Mac using its IP address
>   10.1.10.1, so Edge Inspect will navigate to `http://10.1.10.1:4567`.
>
> So, to get fonts working, you could add both `localhost` and
>   `10.1.10.1` to your kit. However, we don't recommend adding local IPs
>   to kits because they tend to change without warning. (In my example
>   above, the next time I turn on my computer its IP could have changed
>   to 10.1.10.2, but all I would know is that fonts had stopped working
>   on my devices again.)
>
> To work around this, we recommend using some form of "dynamic DNS" —
>   basically, a domain name that is automatically updated with your
>   current IP and therefore will always point to your computer.
>
> If you're using a Mac, the simplest thing would be to use your Mac's
>   Bonjour hostname. Bonjour is a technology built into Mac OS X and iOS
>   to help devices find each other automatically over networks.
>
> To find your Bonjour hostname:
>
> 1. Open System Preferences on your Mac.
> 2. Choose the Sharing icon.
> 3. Your Bonjour hostname will be displayed in the top area, under the "Computer Name" field.
>
> You can add the hostname that appears there to your kit, and use it on
>   any Apple device on your network. For example, my Bonjour name is
>   Somename-rMBP.local, so I can browse to http://Somename-rMBP.local:4567 on
>   any Mac or iOS device and see my Sinatra app.
>
> Unfortunately, this simple solution will only work on Apple devices or
>   Windows PCs with Apple's Bonjour software installed — you can't use
>   this hostname with Android phones or tablets. If you need a hostname
>   that will work on any device, there are a couple of options I'd
>   recommend:
>
> 1. A third-party service called Forward offers a way to easily forward ports from your computer to other devices anywhere on the internet.
>      You can learn more about them and sign up for a 30-day trial here:
>      https://forwardhq.com. Forward will give you a permanent domain name
>      for your forwarded app that you can add to your kit, such as
>      `dev-yourcompany.fwd.wf`.
> 2. 37signals has a free "wildcard DNS" service called xip.io that will automatically forward traffic to a local IP address. You can get your
>      current local IP address by opening System Preferences, then choosing
>      Network. The IP address should be shown in the small text underneath
>      the connection status for whatever connection is active (i.e. has a
>      green dot next to it). Once you have the IP, you can access your
>      computer at [YOUR IP].xip.io. To get fonts working, add *.xip.io to
>      your kit. Remember that your IP may change, so if your site stops
>      being accessible you should check to make sure you have the correct IP
>      address.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what Adobe's support should make public in the first place!